# Cannot load form yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am newbie to yii2. I am trying to create my simple form in yii2 to retrieve password. Here is class code:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\base\Model;



class RetrievePasswordForm extends Model
{
    public $email;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is action code:

```
$model = new RetrievePasswordForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
            return $this->render('retrievepassword-confirm', ['model' => $model]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('retrievepassword', ['model' => $model]);
        }
```

My form looks like this:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
$this->title = 'Retrieve password';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<p>We will send link to retrieve your password to the following email:</p>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['style'=>'width:200px'])?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The problem is that `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` always returns false, so when I am clicking "submit" button, page just reloads.
I am currently working without database. I am just creating form and trying to go to another form, when valid data received in model. Thanks for help.

Comment: Two things: how is your database table looks like and how does your form looks like?

Comment: try not using  &&$model->validate()   .. could be  there are some problems in validation  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I have tried. No changes. Problem is definetely in load method.

Comment: @Qwertenx   . i have posted  an answer with a brief suggestion .. hope is useful

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitally assign the method and the action to the active Form

Then Assuming that your target action is named actionRetrivePassword

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'method' => 'post',
        'action' => Url::to(['/site/retrivepassword']

  ); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain me how to write this url? If my controller's name is SiteController and action's name is actionRetrievepassword, what should be written in url?

Comment: Thanks, but there are no changes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with I feel it's wrong, if this doesn't help, please give more information.

It's a registration form, so I assume you need email and password for that (since you have those columns in database). But you also declared public member `$email` in your model. This removes any value associated to `$email` from database. Therefore, remove this line:

```
public $email;
```

Comment: I am currently working without db. I am just creating form and trying to go to another form, when valid data is received in model.

Comment: You can check for errors like this: `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()); $model->validate()` Then: `var_dump($model->errors); exit;`. After submitting the form, you should be able to see plain text without any style.

Comment: It just displays array(0) { }.

Comment: Can you show post request? (`var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post()); exit;`)

Comment: It displays the same array(0) {}.

Comment: Then it means you're not sending any data. Not sure why is that.